# shortcode display metainformation as linked image

Tags: shortcode, user-meta

I am trying to make this shortcode to display a self made meta field called `qrbase_code_pass_url` as a linked image.
The image should be static, but should get the dynamic URL from the meta field of the current user.

This is what I've got so far.

```
function get_qr_image() {
        global $current_user; // get current user's information
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $qr_url = get_currentuserinfo($current_user->qrbase_code_pass_url,24 );

        return '<a href="'. $qr_url . '"><img src="https://medlem.nexusesport.no/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/add-to-apple-wallet-logo.png"></a>';
}
add_shortcode('get_user_qr', 'get_qr_image');
```

This shortcode only break the page.

Thank you for all input!

Comment: You didn’t close the a tag: `</a>`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I closed the a-tag now, but still the site is blank. 
Console: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()"

Comment: `get_currentuserinfo()` is deprecated and may be what's causing the problem. If you look in the Codex it shows the function to use in its place: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo - and you shouldn't need to call `global $current_user;` which may also be causing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@WebElaine is correct. I had to use the `wp_get_current_user();` and remove `global`.

This is what worked for me

```
function download_to_wallet() {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); // get current user's information
        $qr_url = $current_user->qrbase_code_pass_url;

        return '<a href="'. $qr_url . '"><img class="qr_download" src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/add-to-apple-wallet-logo.png" style="width:200px;"></a>';
}
```